# How to use cakephp find list to retrieve two different field from different Model?

Tags: cakephp

I want to display a drop-down list of the list of student name with its value, `student_user_id`. But the problem is student name is stored in a different model which is hard to align together in `find('list')`, a find function of Cakephp.

I have some code of the model project that already joins tables. When I code the `getStudentList`, it does not know the `User.user_display_user` field.

## Model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
                'User' => array(
                        'className' => 'User',
                        'foreignKey' => false,
                        'conditions' => array('User.user_id = Project.student_user_id')
                )
        );

 function getStudentList()
        {
                $entry = $this->find('list',array('fields' => array('Project.student_user_id','User.user_display_name')));
                return $entry;
        }
```

So: **How** I can **handle this issue?**

Answer (score 4):

You should use containable behavior and tell CakePHP that in this case you want to join those two tables:

```
$entry = $this->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Project.student_user_id', 'User.user_display_name'),
    'contain' => array('User')
));
```

By default joins should not be made until specifically requested - for performance reasons.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Note:
$recursive = 0 would also work but is discouraged to use.

Comment: I try to do as your suggestion but it does not work.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I miss '    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
' command in Model.